# Amcharts4: 'legendSettings' 'itemValueText' to check for empty or undefined value

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

So, I have created a percentage column chart where on bar hover, I am showing the data in tooltip and in legend similar to https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Interacting_with_cursor.
Also I have added % in the end. (I am getting data like 40, 55, 90 which means 40%, 50% and 90% respectively from backend API not like 0.4 or 0.5).
I am displaying the average percentage in the starting also.

```
series.legendSettings.itemValueText = "[bold]{valueY}%[/]";
series.legendSettings.valueText = "(Avg: [bold]{valueY.average.formatNumber('#.##')}%[/])";
```

So in some case for whole data-set one of the column is null or undefined, I am not getting the key itself and this leads to legend display only **%** . On hover it will display **%**.

So my question is - Is there some way where we can check 'itemValueText' or {valueY} to check whether it is 'undefined' and not add % in the end ?
Or is there any other way and I am doing it wrong?
Basically something like -

```
series.legendSettings.itemValueText = "{valueY}";
if (series.legendSettings.itemValueText !== undefined) {           // or check {valueY}
    series.legendSettings.itemValueText = "[bold]{valueY}%[/]";    // Only if value is undefined add % in last
    series.legendSettings.valueText = "(Avg: [bold]{valueY.average.formatNumber('#.##')}%[/])";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`textOutput`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#textOutput_adapter) adapter on the legend's [`valueLabels`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/legend/#valueLabels_property) template to check the final text output based on your template string and adjust accordingly.

```
chart.legend.valueLabels.template.adapter.add("textOutput", function(text, target) {
  if (text === '(Avg: [bold]%[/])') {
    return 'N/A';
  }
  else if (text === '[bold]%[/]') {
    return '';
  }
  return text;
});
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3d4d35c659b91733c90fa82805fc5433?editors=0010)